# C++ executar programa secundario, apenas se o comando for digitado

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
system("F:\\AI\\iapt2.exe");
system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Boa noite, eu tenho esse código certo, ele vai abrir o programa iapt2.exe ao ser executado, porem eu gostaria de inserir um argumento, para que ele fosse executado.
Tipo só abrir o programa se digitar uma palavra chave, é possível?
Como ficaria?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o parâmetro for direcionado para o executável que está tentando abrir ficaria:

```
char command[512];
char arg[64];
scanf("%s", arg);
sprintf(command, "F:\\AI\\iapt2.exe %s", arg); // executa iapt2.exe com o parametro dentro de arg
system(command);
```

Caso seja um parâmetro passado para o seu programa para definir se irá chamar `iapt2.exe` ficará:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){ // argc - quantidade de parâmetros passados
                                 // argv - parâmetros passados
    if(!strcmp(argv[argc-1], "buiatchaca") // argv[argc-1] pega o ultimo parâmetro digitado
        system("F:\\AI\\iapt2.exe");
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```